# How can i Share HLS Streaming on Facebook with Open Graph Tags?

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, http-live-streaming

Here is the scenario..

I want to share HLS Live Streaming(.m3u8) on Facebook and it should play the live video in user's profile..

How can i achieve this..?

Here is my Sample Code..

```
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Content Title'>
 <meta property='og:url' content='https://fb.example.me/ravi'>
 <meta property='og:title' content='Content Title'>
 <meta property='og:image' content='IMAGE LINK'>
 <meta property='og:type' content='video.other'>
 <link rel='canonical' href='https://fb.example.me/ravi'>
 <meta property='og:video' content='M3U8 Link'>
 <meta property='og:video:secure_url' content='HTTPS M3U8 Link'>
 <meta property='og:video:type' content='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
 <meta property='og:video:width' content='472'>
 <meta property='og:video:height' content='296'>
 <meta property='fb:app_id' content='MY FB APP ID'>
```

Please assist me if i am missing anything..?

Comment: You can only embed swf flash files or mp4 videos, nothing else. So you would need a flash player, that takes your m3u8 file as “input” (via URL parameter), and then loads and plays the resources referenced in there itself.

Comment: So how can i play .m3u8 with SWF in FB?

Comment: Flowplayer supports Facebook embeding using Flash: http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/flash/sharing.html. I didn't check it recently so try if it still works.